# In Python, how do I create a string of n characters in one line of code?

Tags: python, string

I need to generate a string with n characters in Python.  Is there a one line answer to achieve this with the existing Python library?  For instance, I need a string of 10 letters:

```
string_val = 'abcdefghij'
```

Comment: Leave "in one line of code" to code obfuscation contests.  When the solution to a problem is naturally written as one line, it will be; otherwise it shouldn't be.  Using it as a goal of its own is a guaranteed path to nasty code.

Comment: Unless, of course, this is homework.  In which case, leave the "in one line of code" but be honest and include the [homework] tag.

Comment: It's actually not a homework question, I just needed a string of n length in my test scripts. I forgot that in Python, a char can be multiplied by n where n is a positive integer to achieve what I want.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3391106/3779480

Answer (score 426, accepted):

To simply repeat the same letter 10 times:

```
string_val = "x" * 10  # gives you "xxxxxxxxxx"
```

And if you want something more complex, like `n` random lowercase letters, it's still only one line of code (not counting the import statements and defining `n`):

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase
n = 10

string_val = "".join(choice(ascii_lowercase) for i in range(n))
```

Answer (score 15):

The first ten lowercase letters are `string.lowercase[:10]` (if you have imported the standard library module `string` previously, of course;-).

Other ways to "make a string of 10 characters": `'x'*10` (all the ten characters will be lowercase `x`s;-), `''.join(chr(ord('a')+i) for i in xrange(10))` (the first ten lowercase letters again), etc, etc;-).

Comment: In Python 3.1.1, it's string.ascii_lowercase actually.

Comment: Yep, python 3 removed `.lowercase` (`ascii_lowercase` is in recent Python 2's as well as in Python 3).

Answer (score 9):

if you just want any letters:

```
 'a'*10  # gives 'aaaaaaaaaa'
```

if you want consecutive letters (up to 26):

```
 ''.join(['%c' % x for x in range(97, 97+10)])  # gives 'abcdefghij'
```

Answer (score 6):

Why "one line"? You can fit anything onto one line.

Assuming you want them to start with 'a', and increment by one character each time (with wrapping > 26), here's a line:

```
>>> mkstring = lambda(x): "".join(map(chr, (ord('a')+(y%26) for y in range(x))))
>>> mkstring(10)
'abcdefghij'
>>> mkstring(30)
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd'
```

Comment: You can fit anything into one-line, eh?  Quite a claim, re: Python :)

Comment: Gregg: Python allows semicolons as statement delimiters, so you can put an entire program on one line if desired.

Comment: You can't do arbitrary flow control with semicolons though.  Nested loops for example.

Answer (score 5):

This might be a little off the question, but for those interested in the randomness of the generated string, my answer would be:

```
import os
import string

def _pwd_gen(size=16):
    chars = string.letters
    chars_len = len(chars)
    return str().join(chars[int(ord(c) / 256. * chars_len)] for c in os.urandom(size))
```

See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7480271/421846) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399465/421846) and `random.py`'s source for more insight.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use repeated letters, you can use the `*` operator:

```
>>> 'a'*5

'aaaaa'
```