# Decode digits in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, rle

I have a problem decoding.
First the string `'44444'` get encoded to `'54'`. (5 times 4)
Now when I want to decode `'54'` its empty.
(It does function with letters)

The algorithm decodes the string `'4a3b2c'` to `'aaaabbbcc'`.
Now when I want to decode `'4a54'` it just gives `'aaaa'` but the right decoding is `'aaaa44444'`. How can I decode this?

Here is the code:

```
def decode_RLE(x):
    decode = ''
    count = ''
    for i in x:
        
        if i.isdigit():
            #append to count
            count += i
        else i: 
   
            decode += i * int(count)
            count = '' 
         
    return decode
```

Comment: you never reach your else. on the first iteration of the for loop i is 5, this is a digit to its append to count. ON the next iteration of your for loop i is 4 which is also a digit so its appended to count. Now there are no more elements in x so the loop finishes. And since you never entered the else decode will return empty

Comment: Well because "5" and "4" are both digits (`.isdigit()` would return True for both). So `54` in your case would not mean 5 x 4 (44444) but 54 x nothing. How do you distinguish between the numbers and actual encoded characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [string multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3391076/13552470):

```
def decode(string):
    output = ''
    for i in range(0, len(string), 2):
        output += int(string[i]) * string[i + 1]
    return output

print(decode("54"))
print(decode("4a54"))
```

Output:

```
44444
aaaa44444
```

You can even use a list comprehension:

```
def decode(s):
    return ''.join(int(s[i]) * s[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(s), 2))
```

Comment: Cool. Wonder what if the string is '124'?  The string itself can be interpreted in different ways...

Comment: @DanielHao It appears that only single digit numbers will be considered.

Answer (score 2):

That is due to the first if condition. After the loop you get count = "54" and decode = "". Then, the function return an empty string.

If the input has only two digits, technically the loop is not necessary. try this code:

```
def decode_RLE(x):
    return int(x[0])*x[1]
```

If the input has more than two digits, a loop and a good old fashioned slicing should work:

```
def decode_RLE(x):
    counts = x[0:len(x):2] #get odd digits
    chars = x[1:len(x):2] #get even digits
    decode = ""
    
    i = 0
    for ch in chars:
        decode += int(counts[i])*chars[i]
        i += 1
    
    return decode
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this doesn't work for `'4a54'`.

Comment: Thank you, Ann. I edit my answer: that should work

Answer (score 1):

By your logic, you only expect the one-digit lengths. If so you can iterate like so:

```py
def decode_rle(x):
    decoded = ''
    iter_x = iter(x)
    for n, c in zip(iter_x, iter_x):
        decoded += c * int(n)
    return decoded
```

But this wouldn't work with two- or more-digit lengths

Answer (score 0):

A flag can fix this, telling the algorithm that the last passed character was a digit.

```
def decode_RLE(x):
    decode = ''
    count = ''
    was_digit = False
    for i in x:

        if was_digit:
            decode += i * int (count)
            count = ''
            was_digit = False
        
        if i.isdigit():
            count += i
            was_digit = True
         
    return decode
```