# generate dummy packets of fixed size

Tags: python, linux, network-programming, udp

Hi I would like to generate dummy packets of fixed size say 1400 bytes using python. After generation I would like to stream it over the network using UDP broadcast along with the sequence numbers for each packet. Is there any possible ways to do this.

Comment: Create an empty 1400 byte large buffer, a counter variable, and just send them over an UDP socket? [This old question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1424005/440558) should help you with your first part.

Comment: what part are you having trouble with? What have you tried? Yes it is possible and not even technically difficult to pull off. Python plays nice with sockets

Comment: wat i want to do is send 100 dummy  packets with the sequence number and retransmit the packets which are lost during transmission. Also I want to know how much amount of time does it require to broadcast one packet using UDP in python. If i can know this I can decide how i can change the interval putting delay between consecutive broadcasts and then send the lost packets.

Answer (score 4):

Try using [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).

A simple UDP packet can be sent using a simple 1-liner such as `send(IP(dst="192.168.0.255")/UDP(dport=0)/("X"*1400))`