# send packet to an ip using pcap_inject

Tags: c++, pcap, libpcap, packet-injection

I am able to send a packet to a specific IP address using scapy like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797624/generate-dummy-packets-of-fixed-size/13798935#13798935).
Now, I am new to `libcap` and I would like to do the same with `pcap_inject()`.  I am unable to find any code snippet online that uses `pcap_inject()` to send to specific **ip address**. Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/send_an_arbitrary_ethernet_frame_using_libpcap.html)

Comment: But this injects a packet on a local device by device name, not the ip address

Comment: Isnt the ARP sending example code in link above redirecting to a specific IP?

Comment: I see but the main function code is missing. All what I see is that the IP parameter is passed to the main function, but it didn't clarify how it was used for the actual redirection

Comment: first,you want to find mac address of interface and default gateway.After,you can generate an data frame.(ethernet headers+ip headers+tcp or udp headers+application layer protocol headers + data)